# Invalid_Grant error when using Refresh Token

Tags: identity, access-token, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, thinktecture

I am using IdentityServer3's Hybrid Flow. I have enabled the offline_access scope inorder to get refresh token. When my access token expires, I am calling `core/connect/token` endpoin. I am passing client_id, client_secret, refresh_token and grant_type (= refresh_token) as part of body. I am getting `invalid_grant` error.

Comment: have you tried turning on logging?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Client configuration should have "RefreshTokenExpiration" attribute set as  TokenExpiration.Absolute and "RefreshTokenUsage" attribute is set to "OneTimeOnly".  This should make it work !